# Use of WonderPush in react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, wonderpush

is it possible to use WonderPush in order to send push notifications in a react-native app ? I want to be able to send a notification. Thanks !

Comment: It certainly is possible. What problems are you facing?

Comment: The thing is that I don't know where to start, what lib to add, what to implements etc.

Answer (score 0):

WonderPush supports React Native.
Check out the [Getting started guide for React Native](https://docs.wonderpush.com/docs/mobile-push-notifications-react-native).

Best,